# Is the default arrow of dropdown(select) in IE removable thru css?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-select

Can I remove the default arrow in a select element? I've done it in chrome and firefox, but not in ie. How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bit tricky, but it works:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed millions of times before. Please do some research before asking here...

Short answer: 
The 'arrow' icon in option selects is nothing you can change with style rules. Your only option is to use an alternative to the builtin option selects. Try the [jquery chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) maybe.

Comment: the reason being that it is inherited from the OS - this may help - http://www.qubesys.com/25-css-form-templates-and-input-styles/